# Confusion regarding the use of different files for the same program in C

Tags: c, compilation

I have som trouble understanding some concepts when it comes to C and different files (I'm used to Java). F.ex. in the file where I have main I need to use another .c file which contains code that is needed to run my program. I have included this file, but I have read that this isn't recommended. What is the right way to include another .c file?

Also, my code is very long (over 1000 lines), so I would like to split into separate files to make it easier to read. How do I do this? I have searched for answers (of course), but I still can't understand it.

Comment: You should never directly include a .c file, but rather its header (.h) file. This also allows you to include precompiled libraries, without requiring access to its source

Comment: You should read up on the C linker. Maybe something like http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html.

Comment: $cc file1.c file2.c file3.c

Comment: It's really that simple? I removed the #include and compiled them together, and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that the maximum length of the file is not specified, files longer than 1000 lines are no longer manageable.

There are header files `.h` and program files `.c`.

Header files are included in other files prior to compilation and preprocessed C. Declarations and definitions used by one or more programs are located in the header files.

The main purpose of the header file is to give the compiler information necessary to verify the coincidence of types of actual and formal parameters and return type of the result.

Variable declarations in header files is a testament to a failed distribution code between program files.

Not allowed nesting header files. At the beginning of the header file must be explicitly specified using the directives `#include` all files necessary for the operation of this file.

A good practice is to use the following construction to prevent multiple inclusion of the same h-file:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H
 ...    /* body of example.h file */
#endif /* EXAMPLE_H */
```

And program files contain all `#define` and `typedef`s, variable declarations, functions etc.

So you will have both `example.h` and `example.c` in your project.

You can split it into `myString.h` and `myString.c` for string functions, `myFile.h` and `myFile.c` for a part of program that deals with file operations and so on.

---

As example of using header files, I can show the following code (that comments above each file is not necessary but considered to be a good practice, so it will be easier to other programmers to understand your code):

```
/************************************************************************
*file: main.c
*synopsis: -
*author: Khlevnoy Y.A.
*written: 20/09/2014
*last modified: 12/10/2014
************************************************************************/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mystring.h"

int main()
{
    /* some code */
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
/************************************************************************
*file: mystring.h
*synopsis: declarations for string UDF-functions, types, constants
*author: Khlevnoy Y.A.
*written: 20/09/2014
*last modified: 12/10/2014
************************************************************************/


#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H
    #include <stdlib.h>

    /// Function finds the position of occurrence of the substring in the string.
    int substr (const char *pStr, const char *pSub);

    /// Function finds the length of the longest common subsequence of two strings.
    int subseq (const char *pStr, const char *pSub);

    /// Function verifies whether input string a palindrome or not.
    int ispal  (const char *pStr);

    /// Function makes as small as possible palindrome out of an input string.
    char* makepal(const char *pStr);

    /// Function parses input string into allocated array of type double.
    double* txt2double(const char *pStr, int *size);

#endif /* MYSTRING_H */
```

.

```
/***********************************************************************
*file: mystring.c
*synopsis: The string UDF-functions use calloc
* to allocate arrays\vectors.
* These functions are declared in the include file "mystring.h".
*related files: none
*author: Khlevnoy Y.A.
*written: 20/09/2014
*last modified: 12/10/2014
************************************************************************/


#include "mystring.h"


int substr(const char *pStr, const char *pSub)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;                           // indexes
    int sizeStr = 0, sizeSub = 0;               // strings' size
    int match = 0;                              // variable to be returned

/* ... and a hundred lines of code */
```

Comment: I just can't seem to wrap my head around these .h files. Do you know of any tutorials "for dummies" on the subject? Somehow it's just very hard for me to understand.

Comment: @user16655, of course, man. For example, this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html

Comment: @user16655, updated my answer. Also noticed have that my update is quite similar to *merlin2011*'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to use a function `foo()` defined in the file `foo.c`, inside a file called `main.c`. There are two approaches.

One is to compile them together as the comment suggested.

```
gcc -o main main.c foo.c
```

Another way is to compile and then link, which is generally more scalable for larger numbers of source files which you may want to separately. In this case, you should have the following files.

### foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    printf("Foo is called\n");    
}
```

### foo.h

```
void foo();
```

### main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
    foo();
}
```

Here is how you would compile:

```
gcc -c main.c 
gcc -c foo.c 
gcc -o main foo.o main.o
```